# Unable to search certain keywords / search results are converted to tag search

Tags: support, search

It seems certain keywords are always converted to a tag search, while others are not. For instance, I can no longer search `php` as a keyword as the search engine automatically converts my search to `[php]`.  On the other hand, `foreach` can be searched as well as `[foreach]`.

What's the purpose of this?  Is there any way to search for these keywords without having my search criteria changed?

Comment: You can use quotes, e.g. [`"php"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22php%22)